# google cloud functions deployment error

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I suddenly keep getting this error and I don't know what else to do with it.  I have updated the npm, firebase cli and other solutions I found

> > Error: Error occurred while parsing your function triggers. Please ensure you have the latest firebase-functions SDK by running "npm i --save firebase-functions@latest" inside your functions folder.
> >
> > Error: Firebase config variables are not available. Please use the latest version of the Firebase CLI to deploy this function.
> >         at init (/Users/serverless/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:51:15)
> >         at Object.config (/Users/serverless/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/config.js:29:9)
> >         at Object.object (/Users/serverless/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/storage.js:41:27)
> >         at Object. (/Users/serverless/functions/index.js:10:42)
> >         at Module._compile (module.js:624:30)
> >         at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:635:10)
> >         at Module.load (module.js:545:32)
> >         at tryModuleLoad (module.js:508:12)
> >         at Function.Module._load (module.js:500:3)
> >         at Module.require (module.js:568:17)

Comment: did you update firebase-functions?

Comment: @PeterHaddad how can I do that?

Comment: The error message tells you to ensure you have the latest firebase-functions SDK by running `npm i --save firebase-functions@latest` inside your functions folder. You'll also need to update your functions to the 1.0 release, as described in the [migration guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#sdk_changes_that_affect_all_background_non_http_functions).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I have updated the firebase functions  and run npm i --save firebase-functions@latest

Comment: @jone2 have you tried the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have this structure:

```
myproject
 +- .firebaserc    
 |                 
 |
 +- firebase.json  
 |
 +- functions/     
   |
   +- .eslintrc.json   
   |
   +- package.json 
   |
   +- index.js      
   |
   +- node_modules/
```

then in the functions directory do the following to update firebase-functions:

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest --save
```

firebase-admin:

```
npm install firebase-admin@5.11.0 --save
```

and firebase-cli:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
```